# Как в Firebird в select запросе при помощи функции REPLACE найти в поле все апострофы и заменить на обратный слеш с апострофом?

Tags: firebird, replace

Есть стандартная функция
SELECT REPLACE(adv.recomend, 'beer', 'tea') FROM rdb$database

Как сделать чтобы функция нашла все апострофы в поле и проставила перед ними обратный слэш?

Что то типа такого...
SELECT REPLACE(adv.rec, ''', '\'') FROM rdb$database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](http://www.ibase.ru/files/firebird/langref25rus/index.html)

Если литерал апострофа требуется в строковой константе, то он может быть «экранирован» другим предшествующим апострофом. Например,

```
'Mother O''Reilly's home-made hooch'
```

Следовательно в вашем случае требуемая команда будет выглядеть следующм образом:

```
SELECT REPLACE(adv.rec, '''', '\''') FROM rdb$database
```